# can we access the applications internet data in android?

Tags: android, instagram

I want to know that if i can trace applications like `instagram` data URLs?something like if the app send a request to `EXAMPLE.COM`...can i get the URL?i mean the "EXAMPLE.COM".
do we have something in android that trace the internet data s?
i just found nothing in the web.i just found this from Google that check the Internet.

```
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    ...
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
        // fetch data
    } else {
        // display error
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: So you want to track another app's use of the internet?  Yeah, that isn't a massive security hole or anything.  Thankfully no, you can't without a rooted device.

Comment: what do you mean by tracing the internet's data? sounds like an impossible thing to do - maybe you could try to explain the problem you want to solve. i.e. why do you want to trace the internet's data?

Answer (score 0):

Admit you can check what others apps send/receive, which might be possible with some hacks.

Your problem will be that most apps uses SSL connection to exchange datas between client and servers. SO even if you could catch a request, you won't be able to read it.